# Angular displays only ID number from Java REST

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I am making CRUD app with SpringBoot and Angular. I am using MySQL to this, and when I make POST request in Postman I can see all my date displayed in JSON file. So in Angular I have service with:

```
export class GetdataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAllTodos() {
    return this.http.get < Todo[] > ('http://wwww.localhost:8081/todos');
  }
}
```

My Component where I am saving data:

```
export class TaskListComponent implements OnInit {
  todos: Todo[];

  constructor(private getDataService: GetdataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshTodos();
  }

  refreshTodos() {
    console.log(this.getDataService.getAllTodos().subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.todos = response;
      }
    ));
  }
}

export class Todo {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public description: string,
    public status: boolean,
    public date: Date
  ) {}
}
```

In `console.log` I am able to see my JSON format with correct data from database. When I start angular application I do not have any errors in console but on my browser I can see only id numbers. Do not know what might be wrong in this case.

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Target Date</th>
      <th>is Completed?</th>
      <th>Update</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr *ngFor="let todo of todos">
      <td>{{todo.description}}</td>
      <td>{{todo.id}}</td>
      <td>{{todo.status}}</td>
      <td>{{todo.date}}</td>    
    </tr>

    </tbody>    
  </table>    
</div>
```

[image: Also, status is 200]

Comment: according to your screenshot todo.description should be todo.taskDescription etc. Generally add "todo" as a prefix after a dot.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I have not known that they must have be the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have the incorrect property name, which is causing this issue.

Comment: It was a case, now I know that JSON "key" must match in Angular :)